# how to pass value in textfield in crystalreport from textbox in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, parameters, crystal-reports

I want to have one field in my crystal report in vb.net, I want to display in this textfield is the value of textbox in vb.net form.

I made parameters named "prog_user" and set the value of this to the textbox.text but it doesn't display anything.

heres my code I put it on report_viewer_shown events in vb.net

```
Dim crpath, filepath As String



        Private Sub rpt_viewer_Shown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Shown               

                       cryrpt = New CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument()
                        crpath = "D:\LEGAL\NLRC_new_022213\NLRC"
                        filepath = crpath & "\Legal Records.rpt"
                        cryrpt.Load(filepath)

                        cryrpt.RecordSelectionFormula = "{Command.CaseNo} = " & case_no
                        crviewer.ReportSource = cryrpt

                        Legal_Records1.SetParameterValue("prog_user", textbox1.text)
                        crviewer.Refresh()

end sub
```

what might be the problems if this? the other data in my crystal report display the correct value from the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try clearing it before adding the values

```
With cryrpt
   .ParameterFields("prog_user").CurrentValues.Clear()
   .ParameterFields("prog_user").CurrentValues.Add(Textbox1.text)
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
 cryrpt = New CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument()
 crpath = "D:\LEGAL\NLRC_new_022213\NLRC"
 filepath = crpath & "\Legal Records.rpt"
 cryrpt.Load(filepath)

 cryrpt.RecordSelectionFormula = "{Command.CaseNo} = " & case_no
 cryrpt.ParameterFields("prog_user").CurrentValues.Clear()
 cryrpt.ParameterFields("prog_user").CurrentValues.Add(textbox1.text)

 crviewer.ReportSource = cryrpt
 crviewer.Refresh()
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work using textbox info. with CR:

```
    Dim report As New CrystalReport1
    Dim objText As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.TextObject = report.ReportDefinition.Sections(1).ReportObjects("Text1")
    objText.Text = Me.TextBox1.Text
    FrmPrint.CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = report
    FrmPrint.Show()
```